# Codeigniter Run multiple application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I m not having luck working with two applications (admin and client) with same installation of the codeigniter.

I referred to many tutorials and did

- I created subfolder "admin" inside application folder and cut and pasted all subdirectories into it.
- I copied and pasted admin folder inside application folder and renamed it "client"
- and in main index.php I set application folder path to "application/admin". But this works only for admin section, and to run client I have to change application folder path again in index.php. This way I cannot run both admin and client simultaneously.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating subfolders inside the application folder? Separate your users from your admin using the controllers. All the folders inside the main application folder should remain the same, you can obviously make new folders inside the main ones, ie controllers/admin or views/admin to separate out the content.

Comment: Why you want to separate for admin and client ? i guess you can use HMVC in codeigniter ..

Comment: @RickCalder. I think this one will be an easier solution to create subfolders within controllers, views and models

Comment: @Sharmila See if this helps:
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/

Comment: @RickCalder, I created subfolder 'admin' in each MVC, and copied each files to respective subfolder. when I m trying to access http://localhost/testproject/admin, this gave 404 error, before moving to 'admin' subfolder, it was working

Comment: Why don't you try [ACL](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/213845/#990514) library?

Comment: If you are interested inadding sub modules,try HMVC

Comment: Now you need to look into the routing Sharmila, look in the userguide for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better explained 3 approaches to get it done. I preferred the 2nd one

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 4):

You can find the following solution helpful:

1.Create a folder 'admin' in the root directory of CodeIgniter.

2.Copy the 'index.php' file inside 'admin' folder.

3.Change the following variables of the 'index.php' file inside 'admin' folder

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application/admin';
```

4.Create a '.htaccess' file inside 'admin' folder and use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

5.Set the $config['base_url'] to 'your url/admin' inside 'application/admin/config/config.php' and autoload 'url' helper.

6.Now you can access the admin panel using 'your url/admin'.

7.Follow the same procedure for 'client'.

Comment: Nice and easy solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From the codeigniter documentation:

> Note:  Each of your applications will need its own index.php file
>   which calls the desired application. The index.php file can be named
>   anything you want.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html