# How to use two or more applications in one code igniter installation?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two projects one is CRM and other one is Project Management. I would like to merge these projects in one application folder so that i can use resources of each other. I tried different solution but none of them all me to share resources.
remember that both projects are completely developed.

Comment: How you want to request CRM and Project Management? In one domain or in different domains?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I would like to keep in one domain

Comment: Create subfolders for Controllers, Models and Views for CRM and Project Management. Except those that are common for both. I think commond resources will be model or view.

Comment: But there are some file which are common in names but their content is different so in which case i get the error of resources not found.

Comment: Then create subfolders: `application/model/crm, application/controllers/crm,  application/model/pm application/controllers/pm` and move files to those directories.

Comment: you know what these two projects are already built. so if i change the folder structure it will be broken.

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744008/codeigniter-run-multiple-application

Comment: I already gone through this link but not 100% relevant to my requiremrnt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113200/discussion-between-medet-ahmetson-atabayev-and-waqar-adil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out the best thing that is HMVC for such type of projects where individual applications will become modules and have access to eachother's controller modal and view.

Answer (score 1):

Create Subfolders for both applications in controller, models and views for a proper separation

**For resources they share, create a app common also and access that from there**

```
    application/model/crm
    application/model/product_management
    application/model/common

    application/controllers/crm
    application/controllers/product_management
    application/controllers/common

    application/views/crm
    application/views/product_management
    application/views/common
```

Comment: I will try this solution and get back to you if it is successful but I need some time. Thanks for the solution by the way