# Access another app inside a codeingter application

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've an CI app with all it's necessary files and folders.

I want to put another app inside a codeigniter.

Suppose `www.example.com` is my CI app and by default `www.example.com/xyz` would call some controller but I want to got the xyz folder which has another app. How is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "another app"?

Comment: I think your problem is already solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744008/codeigniter-run-multiple-application

Comment: @DFriend another app means I don't want to create two different folders. I just want to add some rule so that it treats everything after the base_url() as controller except that xyz.